# int-http:outbound-gateway reply-channel 'stalls'

Tags: http, spring-integration, gateway, reply, outbound

I'm creating a Spring Integration prototype using Spring Boot.

I have a 'hub' that accepts console input and sends that to an separate socket/tcp application.

The tcp application echos what it was sent in its reply to the hub.

The hub then takes the tcp response & sends it to a separate restful/http application.
The http application echos what is was sent back to the hub.

I'm stuck on the hub's int-http:outbound-gateway which send a request to http. When i omit the 'reply-channel', i can enter more than one bit of text and send to the tcp application. That reply is forwarded to the http application & printed in the console.
However, when i include a reply-channel, i can send one message to the tcp application (the http app receives it) and then the hub application 'stalls'; i type messages in console, hit 'enter' but nothing happens.

Here's my config:

```
    <!-- TO tcp application/server -->
    <int:channel id="input" />

    <int:gateway id="simple.gateway"
        service-interface="com.foo.SimpleGateway"
        default-request-channel="input"/>

    <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
        type="client"
        host="localhost"
        port="4444"
        single-use="true"
        so-timeout="10000"/>

    <int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
        request-channel="input"
        reply-channel="clientBytes2StringChannel"
        connection-factory="client"
        request-timeout="10000"
        reply-timeout="10000"/>     

    <int:object-to-string-transformer id="clientBytes2String"
        input-channel="clientBytes2StringChannel"
        output-channel="broadcast.channel" />

    <int:channel id="broadcast.channel" />

    <int:recipient-list-router id="tcp.broadcast.list"
        input-channel="broadcast.channel">
        <int:recipient channel="to.http" />
        <!-- other channels to broadcast to -->
    </int:recipient-list-router>

    <!-- TO HTTP restful endpoint -->
    <!-- this sends the requests -->
    <int:channel id="to.http" />

<!--    <int-http:outbound-gateway id="http-outbound-gateway"  -->
<!--        request-channel="to.http" -->
<!--        url="http://localhost:8080/howdy?message={msg}" -->
<!--        http-method="GET" -->
<!--        expected-response-type="java.lang.String" -->
<!--        charset="UTF-8"> -->
<!--        <int-http:uri-variable name="msg" expression="payload"/> -->
<!--    </int-http:outbound-gateway> -->

    <int-http:outbound-gateway id="http-outbound-gateway" 
        request-channel="to.http"
        url="http://localhost:8080/howdy?message={msg}"
        http-method="GET"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
        charset="UTF-8"
        reply-channel="from.http.pubsub.channel">
        <int-http:uri-variable name="msg" expression="payload"/>
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>

<!-- http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html -->
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="from.http.pubsub.channel" />

<bean id="inboundHTTPPrinterService"
        class="com.foo.service.InboundHTTPPrinterService"/> 

<int:service-activator id="inboutdHttpPrintServiceActivator"
    ref="inboundHTTPPrinterService"
    input-channel="from.http.pubsub.channel"
    method="printFromHttp"/>

</beans>
```

In its final form, i want the HTTP response to be printed somewhere AND forwarded to a separate AMQP application.

Answer (score 0):

Your description isn't clear, however, I guess, you mean some issue in here:

```
<int:service-activator id="inboutdHttpPrintServiceActivator"
    ref="inboundHTTPPrinterService"
    input-channel="from.http.pubsub.channel"
    method="printFromHttp"/>
```

It would be great to see the `printFromHttp()` source code, but according your fears it seems for that the method is `void`.

To send message back to the `replyChannel` in the headers you should return something from your service method. Looks like in your case it is just enough the same `payload` or `message` if that.

Comment: that resolved the 'stall' issue (i added a String return type to <code>printFromHttp()</code>. What i'm seeing now, is that the reply from TCP is not recorded in my "main" where i'm sending the message but after the round-trip from the http client.

Comment: As I said: your description isn't clear. Maybe we'll consider to close this one for the `stalls` issue and open an new one, closer to your current problem and already with its environment? Consider also to share some logs/Exceptions on the matter. Sorry, I just don't understand you with such an info in the question.